# Make image in card smaller (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, card

I have a card and I want to insert a picture there. But the picture size is too big. I want to make it smaller. But I can't change it. It goes like this :
[image: Image size won't changed]

Here's the code:

```css
    .media .img {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-8 mx-auto">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-content">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="media ">
                                                <div class="align-self-center patient">
                                                    <img src="{{ asset('images/patient.png') }}">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="media-body text-right">
                                                    <h3>Patient</h3>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: instead of writing `.media .img` remove the dot before img so it will be `.media img`

Answer (score 1):

you won't need `.media .img` , just type `.media img` because img isn't a **class**